# How to center <form> and <span>?

Tags: html, css

This is my code and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nto6yfuj/):

```css
.sortby {
  text-align:center;
}

.sortby span {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortby">
<span> Sort By  </span>
<form>
<select>
<option>I want to center </option>
<option>I want to center too </option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

I tried different combinations of `left:50%,transform:translate(-50%), display:inline,block, margin: auto` etc...But nothing seems to work

Comment: Explain question clearly

Comment: For which element you are trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `display: inline-block;` to the form and removed `float: left;` form `span`.

```css
.sortby {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortby">
  <span> Sort By  </span>
  <form>
    <select>
<option>I want to center </option>
<option>I want to center too </option>
</select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is you fix

```css
.sortby {
  text-align:center;
}

.sortby span {
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortby">
<span> Sort By  </span>
<form>
<select>
<option>I want to center </option>
<option>I want to center too </option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:inline-block;` property to `<form>`  and remove `float:left;` to `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.sortby {
  text-align:center;
}

form {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sortby">
<span> Sort By  </span>
<form>
<select>
<option>I want to center </option>
<option>I want to center too </option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you better change your css code here for centering the div tag

```
.sortby {
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}
```

if you want center the span also change the code to

```
.sortby span{
 text-align:center
}
```